# SSL certificate propagation issue with custom domain on Bluemix app

Tags: node.js, ssl, dns, ibm-cloud, bluemix-app-scan

I uploaded my `SSL certificate` in the section of my `custom domain` in the space of my organization. I linked the domain with my application and I have created the `CNAME` record in my DNS to my broken app `xxxxx-gb.bluemix.net .eu`.

[image]

When I try to reach my application through my domain custom, I served me the `Bluemix certificate` and not mine.
[image]

I tried to add a proxy on my server (NodeJS) but the situation does not change.

```
 app.enable('trust proxy');
 app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.secure) {
                // request was via https, so do no special handling
                next();
        } else {
                // request was via http, so redirect to https
                res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
        }
  });
```

How can I fix the problem ? I need my certificate, to call my API, from my mobile application, it is the certificate must necessarily be mine and then TRUSTED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map the `CNAME` to the secure endpoint for the Bluemix region you are using, in your case it should be `secure.eu-gb.bluemix.net`.

When receiving the request from your custom domain Bluemix will map it internally to your app.

More details in the documentation link below:

https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/updapps.html#domain

Comment: Same thing is happening with me, did you have any luck @jay ?